# How to Transfer Data From JFrame to another JFrame with this situation?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton, jtextfield

How can I transfer data into my other frame cause I'm doing If else statements in one Jbutton and so that the confirm button will also check the text fields that are empty and I also want it to act as a button to open my next frame then send that data to the next frame. My code doesn't seem to work other functions work and it also opens the other frame but doesn't display the data I need like: Name and will display the name in the other frame, need some help :(

```
JButton confirm = new JButton("Sign Up");
    confirm.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            
            UserInfo a = new UserInfo();
            
            
            if(!firstname.getText().trim().isEmpty() && !lastname.getText().trim().isEmpty() &&  password.getPassword().length != 0 && pass2.getPassword().length != 0
                    && !address.getText().trim().isEmpty() ) {
            
                String inputText = firstname.getText();
                a.D1.setText(inputText);    
            a.frame2.setVisible(true);
            frame.dispose(); }
            else
            
            if(firstname.getText().trim().isEmpty()) {
                missingfirst.setText("Please Add Your First Name.");
        
            }
            if(lastname.getText().trim().isEmpty()) {
                missinglast.setText("Please Add Your Last Name.");
            }
            
            if(address.getText().trim().isEmpty()) {
                missingadd.setText("Please Enter An Address.");
            }
            if(password.getPassword().length == 0) {
                missingpass.setText("Please Add A Password.");
            }
            
            if(pass2.getPassword().length == 0) {
                missingrepass.setText("Please Re-Type Your Password.");
            
            }
            else if (!(password.getPassword().equals(pass2.getPassword()))) {
                missingrepass.setText("Password Doesn't Match.");
            }
        
        }
```

[This is my 2nd Frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v0ZED.png)

Comment: One way to pass data would be for your code to pass one or more objects to the new JFrame. I would probably handle this with a CardLayout rather than two frames, though.

Comment: 1) See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556) 2) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).